# How to broadcast udp data on specific interface ip(lancard ip) in C# .net

Tags: c#, udp, udpclient

I have two lan cards in my pc. I searched how to broadcast udp data on specific interface ip of lan card as per my requirement, but not found any similar snippet of code. So please suggest a way or provide related code if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: or this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192548/specifying-what-network-interface-an-udp-multicast-should-go-to-in-net

Comment: You can *Bind* to one of your IPs to send your broadcast messages.